# Getting entity body from HttpURLConnection

Tags: http, httpurlconnection, digest-authentication

I'm currently writing a little library to standardize the use of `HttpURLConenction`'s in my android-projects.

In one of my projects I'm communicating with a server using Http Digest to authenticate the user. The default java `HttpUrlConnection` doesn't support digest but I've managed to write a simplified digest auth (qop=auth) which is working pretty well.

For future projects I want to enable my library to use auth-int. Therefor I need to modify the construction of the A2 Hash and include the HTTP entity body ([see RFC 7616 Section 3.4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7616#section-3.4.3)).

To do so I thought about extracting the full HTTP request from the `URLConnection` and then throwing out the unneeded stuff. Unfortunately I was unable to find a way to do this.
Extracting the single headerfields is possible by `.getContentEncoding()`, `.getContentLength()`, `.getContentType()` etc. . But with this I can't ensure that the order of the entity I'm reconstructing with the get-methods is the same as in the request and this might lead to a 401.

To sum it up:

Is there a way to extract the full request (or better only the entity body) from a `HttpURLConnection`?